# Cannot connect Mapr-tables on Mapr-FS?

Tags: linux, mapr

Hj all,

I'm use Mapr M7 Edition on Centos 6.4, 64bit. I'm test MapR-tables on MapR but click MapR-tables -->

> **Error Home directory (/user/root) is missing for this user. Please create it in order to cache the recent tables administered by this user.**

- I'm read Mapr doc show: http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Setting+Up+MapR-FS+to+Use+Tables

> Set Up User Directories for MapR Tables
>
> Because MapR tables, like files, are created by users, MapR tracks table activity in a user's home directory on the cluster. Create a home directory at /user/ on your cluster for each user that will access MapR tables. **After mounting the cluster on NFS, create these directories with the standard Linux mkdir command in the cluster's directory structure.**
>   When a user foo does not have a corresponding /user/foo directory on the cluster, querying MapR for a list of tables that belong to that user generates an error reporting the missing directory.

- but I do not know where that /user/ is created?
- I'm mount to client Linux: OK

And help me create directory, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you mount the NFS partition in `/mapr`, you should create the directory `/mapr/<your.cluster.name>/user/root`. Another way to do it, is to run the command as mapr user, which may already have a home directory in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just do

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/<username>
hadoop fs -chown <username> /user/<username>
```

Then create your tables from the UI.